# How to make a "create-only" non-editable field in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

im looking for some solution about make a "create-only" field on django admin using models.
I saw some questions before, but no one can answer the core question: the field should appear when the user are creating on admin panel, but i dont want to be able to edit.

**models.py**

```
class Fonte(Always):
    source_slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Fonte)
class FonteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     readonly_fields = ['source_slug']
```

the "readonly_fields" solves the problem in the matter of editing in the future, but ends up forbidding when creating.

Problem: Im using this field to make a hash and i dont wanna this change evermore.. I thought about using a second field that would generate a hash on top of the editable one field in the creation, after that the field would be "dead", but that seems to me to be contrary to the 2 way of normalization.
Is there any more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `get_readonly_fields` in your Admin class like that:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return ['source_slug'] 
    return []
```